# approximate Fourier transform

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F}$ stand for the Fourier transform. Suppose $f : [-\delta/2,\delta/2] \to \mathbb{C}$ is a "nice" function. Is it true that $$\left|\mathcal{F} \left(e^{imx} \left(e^{ix^2}-1 \right)f(x) \right)(\xi) \right| \leq |\delta|^2 \left|\mathcal{F}\left(e^{imx}f(x) \right)(\xi)\right|?$$

If so, how can I prove it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe try Young's convolution inequality?

Comment: What does "nice" mean? Is the inequality referring to the modulus of any one particular sample of the FT? Or the total power in the frequency domain?

Comment: After working out the FT, I get $\left| \mathcal{F}(\xi - \xi_m) \ast \alpha e^{i\beta \xi^2} - \mathcal{F}(\xi - \xi_m) \right| \leq \left| \delta \right|^2 \left| \mathcal{F}(\xi - \xi_m) \right|$, where I think $\beta = 1/4$, I forget what $\alpha$ is, and $\xi_m = 2\pi/m$. But I don't see how to draw a conclusion without knowing what $\operatorname{f}$ is or what "nice" means.